# Can not find my project settings in Sublime/Mavensmate

Tags: salesforce, sublimetext3

I am using MavensMate Build 3124, which requires a separate MevensMate app in combination with Salesforce. I can now no longer find my project settings, meaning I can not refresh from my Salesforce server using API 38.0. This keeps resetting my package.xml to v37.0. I have set my Global Settings to use API v38.

Where can I find my project settings so that I can refesh using API 38?

Answer (score 0):

look for the following file in your repository:

[your-project-name].sublime-project

add the following

```
{
    "mm_api_version" : 38.0
}
```